# MySQL: Count rows with conditional value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how much the user is login and how much they fail to and success to.

The category column is varchar (the stupidity of the ex programmer) while the value is only 1 or 0 only.

If 1 they success, if 0 it means fail.

```
$loginForced = " SELECT
                    Count(categori) AS login,                       
                    Count(CASE WHEN categori = '1' THEN categori ELSE 0 END) AS success,                        
                    Count(CASE WHEN categori = '0' THEN categori ELSE 0 END) AS fail                        
                 FROM 
                    log
                 WHERE  email = '".$personal."' ";
```

Comment: change the conditional count to conditional `sum` `SUM(CASE WHEN ....`

Comment: I have tried it, but the result is wierd.

Comment: In that case you need to provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Bellow answers give me some examples of expected result. :D YaW

Comment: Now I am just waiting for people to vote which one I need to accept. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum` with condition:

```
$loginForced = "select count(`categori`) as `login`,                       
                       sum(`categori` = '1') as `success`,                        
                       sum(`categori` = '0') as `fail`                        
                from `log`
                where `email` = '".$personal."' ";
```

Comment: I just note that this answer makes the (very reasonable) assumption that `categori` is never `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want t just skip the `ELSE` in the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT Count(categori) AS login,                       
       Count(CASE WHEN categori = '1' THEN categori END) AS success,                        
       Count(CASE WHEN categori = '0' THEN categori END) AS fail                        
FROM log
WHERE  email = '".$personal."' ";
```

`COUNT` takes into account *all non-null values*, so using `ELSE 0` is essentially pointless, since `0` is going to be counted just like any other value.

Comment: My fault to set the else condition. Thanks anyway. :D